# Create Refresh token like "createToken" method with User Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-passport

I want to create mobile authentication with SMS authorization code.
So I need to create token for each user without use Passport APIs.
thus I create personal client according to the following:

```
php artisan passport:client --personal
> Customer
```

and try to create token with `createToken`

```
$user = User::find(1);
$token = $user->createToken('Customer');
return $token->toArray();
```

it was created but I don't have any expire token to refresh token when it will be expired.

Comment: Personal token has no expiry time thats why no expire and refresh token

Answer (score 0):

Create a command that handles deleting the token.
Then scheduling that command in Kernel.php to run daily (for example).
So, essentially you are creating a command that runs daily and that command clears out all of the tokens.

If you don't know how to create commands or schedule commands in Kernel, leave a comment and I will walk you through it. Or you can google it.